# Reading a C++ vector by value vs by reference

Tags: c++, vector, dictionary, reference, definition

This is a fundamental pointer question, but this is baffling me for a while now. I have implemented a weighted graph, using C++ `map` as an underlying datastructure as follows:

```
std::map<int, std::vector<Edge> > edgeList;
```

This map holds the node id (an `int`) as the key and the list of edges on this node using a `vector` as a value

I have initialized the edge list for each node as follows:

```
for(int i = 0; i< n; i++){
        std::vector<Edge> vi;
        edgeList.insert(std::make_pair(i,vi)); // initialize with empty vector (at least, that's the intent)
    }
```

Now, while adding an edge to the graph, when I try to retrieve the edge list `vector` corresponding to each node as follows:

```
std::vector<Edge> vList = edgeList.at(v); // v is the node id here
```

an empty `vector` vList is returned, even though, I have added edges to that vList earlier.

On the other hand,

```
std::vector<Edge> &vList = edgeList.at(v);
```

seems to be working fine for my purpose. Can anyone please explain why the first implementation doesn't work and the second does?

Edit:
Code for adding the edges to the graph is as follows:

```
void Graph::addEdge(Edge e){

    // retrieve start and end node for this edge
    int v = e.either(); // returns either end of the edge
    int w = e.other(v);

    // retrieve edge lists for these nodes
    std::vector<Edge> vList = edgeList.at(v); // doesn't work
    std::vector<Edge> wList = edgeList.at(w); // doesn't work

    // add this edge to the list of edges
    vList.push_back(e);
    wList.push_back(e);
}
```

Comment: If the vector in the map has elements, there is no way your first version can give you an empty one.

Comment: Show the code that adds edges.  I suspect you're adding them to the vector returned by `edgeList.at(v)`, but in the working case you've used a reference.

Comment: @paddy: That's true. So, what does `edgeList.at(v)` really return? If I am overwriting the edgeList, I don't understand how.

Comment: It returns a reference to the contained type.  So you can do `edgeList.at(v).push_back(e)`.  Or you can store the result as a reference and operate on that.  But if you assign it to a non-reference value, it will be copied and thus any changes you make to that value will not be reflected in your map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `std::map::at` function returns a reference to the `std::vector` at the given index. When you assign this to a non-reference variable, you will be making a copy of the vector. Any insert operations you do, will be on the copy of the vector, which goes out of scope at the end of the method while the vector you were aiming for just sits in the map happily and unaffected.

Instead, if you add the `&`, then `vList` will really become an alias of the actual vector that is stored in your map. Now, any changes made to `vList` are really made to the map element. If you wish, you can look at the reference as a pointer in disguise. In that case, you would explicitly write

```
std::vector<Edge> *vList = &edgeList.at(v);
```

and not, for example,

```
std::vector<Edge> *vList = new std::vector();
*vList = edgeList.at(v);
```

Actually, the following example demonstrates the point more clearly:

```
using namespace std;

int i = 0;

int& get_i()
{
    return i;
}

int main()
{
   cout << "i = " << i << ", &i = " << &i << endl;

   int j = get_i();
   j++;
   cout << "i = " << i << ", j = " << j << ", &j = " << &j << endl; 

   int& k = get_i();
   k++;
   cout << "i = " << i << ", k = " << k << ", &k = " << &k << endl; 

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do this:

```
std::vector<Edge> vList = edgeList.at(v);
```

You're creating a **copy** of the vector in the map.

When you do this:

```
std::vector<Edge> &vList = edgeList.at(v);
```

You're getting a reference to that vector.

If you add elements to the copy, they won't be added to the map (since it's just a copy, and has no relation to the original anymore). If you add elements to the reference, it's added to the map, because it's the same vector.

Comment: So the = operator performs actual deep copy operation? :O. This is so unlike java (analogously). Thanks a ton for the help :)

Comment: @swap_1712 The difference is that in C++, everything is a value by default (unless you explicitly make them references or pointers), while in Java most things are automatically references. When you assign one value to another value, the only thing it can do it make a copy. It's not necessarily a *deep* copy though, since the contents may not change (for example, if you copy a vector of pointers, the pointers will continue pointing to the same values).